# AJAX call doesnt appear to ever take place

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I'm trying to use ajax in combination with jQuery datatables for dynamic tables, the problem is, the `sAjaxSource` parameter isn't making a post request (I usually use chromes web tools to check the headers and response code, where I would expect a POST method with a response). The script is loading, there are no errors for jquery in the console either. How can I get this ajax call to happen?

Below is jquery for the table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#datatable-courses').dataTable({

    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false, // disable auto width calculation
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',

    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sServerMethod":"POST",
    "sAjaxSource": "admin/courses/ajax_get_courses",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000]],
    "aaSorting": [[0, 'asc']],
    "aaSorting": [], // sorting off initially
    "aoColumns": [
        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "60px" },
        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "250px" },
        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "70px" },
        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "70px",


        }
    ],

    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "my_csrf_name", "value": $.cookie('my_csrf_cookie') } );
    }
}).fnSetFilteringDelay(700);
```

Here's a look at my controller, though I doubt the issue is here:

```
 public function ajax_get_courses()
{
    if ( ! $this->input->is_ajax_request() || ! is_server_request_method('POST')) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->load->model('courses_model');

    $data = $this->courses_model->ajax_get_courses();

    echo $data;
    flush();
    exit();

}
```

ADDITIONA INFORMATION :

Using jquery Datatables 0.7,  codeigniter

config var for csrf token is set to true.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding whole URL in sAjaxSource as

http://example.com/admin/courses/ajax_get_courses

Answer (score -1):

Use this method for sending a CSRF token:

```
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
    aoData.push( { "name": "csrf_test_name", "value": $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name') } );
},
```

Note: Don't forgot to include jquery.cookie.js in the head or footer of the page

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain how the token fixes the problem with sAjaxSource